# How can I access ListViewDataItem from an ItemTemplate without using code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access `ListViewDataItem` from inside an `ItemTemplate` in an ASP.NET C# page  that does not have code behind.

the page is very simple and does not have any code on it. it is dynamicaly binds to a datasource on page and shows a list of data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Container` in your List View Template. It will give you current `ListViewDataItem`